# Smart Target vs Marketo Personalization

Tags: smarttarget

My company currently uses Marketo for Inbound Marketing and SDL Tridon (13, I believe) for our CMS.

We want to do more web personalization in the coming year, and we are trying to decide between SDL's Smart Target service and Marketo Real Time Personalization.

Obviously, the fact that we currently use both is complicating the decision.

Since we are using Marketo as a Lead tool, it seems like that would be the logical choice, Smart Target adding another level of complexity - and honestly the $ amount of the implementation is quite high.

Was wondering if anyone here has experience with both these tools and could comment.

Thanks.